# android fade out animation

Tags: android, animation

I would like to fade out an progress bar, if my http request will be done.

this is my code.

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView LoginInfo;
    ProgressBar LoadingCircle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        LoginInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.LoginInfo);
        LoadingCircle = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.LoadingCircle);


        RequestData();

    }

    private class LoadingDataURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONArray> {





        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... params) {
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            JSONArray response = new JSONArray();

            try {
                url = new URL(params[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                String responseString = readStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

                response = new JSONArray(responseString);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null)
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
            }



            return response;
        }



        private String readStream(InputStream in) {
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            try {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            ObjectAnimator fadeOutLoadingCircle = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(LoadingCircle, LoadingCircle.ALPHA, 1,0);
            fadeOutLoadingCircle.setDuration(1500);
            AnimatorSet fadeOut = new AnimatorSet();
            fadeOut.play(fadeOutLoadingCircle);
            fadeOut.start();

            return response.toString();
        }
    }





    // Request Data
    public void RequestData() {
        if (isInternetAvailable() == true) {
            LoadingDataURL client = new LoadingDataURL();
            client.execute("https://xxxx");
        }
    }


    // Internet available?
    public boolean isInternetAvailable() {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {
            Process ipProcess = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 8.8.8.8");
            int     exitValue = ipProcess.waitFor();
            return (exitValue == 0);


        } catch (IOException e)          { e.printStackTrace();}
        catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace();}
        return false;
    }
}
```

But the Animation will not be executed.
if i put the animation code into my onCreate = it works.
any ideas? :/

But the Animation will not be executed.
if i put the animation code into my onCreate = it works.
any ideas? :/

But the Animation will not be executed.
if i put the animation code into my onCreate = it works.
any ideas? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do below things

1) Try to put your **animtion code** in

> onPostExecute()

of you AsyncTask class as it will execute after your http request will be done.

or

2) just write `LoadingCircle.setVisibility(View.GONE);` inside onPostExecute()

Answer (score 1):

```
private static void ImageViewAnimatedChange(Context c, final ImageView v) {    
final Animation anim_out=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(c,android.R.anim.fade_out);

        anim_out.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener()
        {
            @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
            @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
            @Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
            {
                v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }
        });
        v.startAnimation(anim_out);
    }
```

/res/anim/fade_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true" >

    <alpha
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="0.0" />

</set>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
ObjectAnimator fadeOutLoadingCircle = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(LoadingCircle, LoadingCircle.ALPHA, 1,0);
        fadeOutLoadingCircle.setDuration(1500);
        AnimatorSet fadeOut = new AnimatorSet();
        fadeOut.play(fadeOutLoadingCircle);
        fadeOut.start();
```

to:

```
LoadingCircle.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(3000).start();
```

you can change the duration to any time you want. Right now, it is set to 3 seconds

Comment: this doesnt works, too. if i put your code into the oncreat = it works, if i put your code before the line `return response.toString();` = it doesnt work

Comment: Add a Log message before `return response.toString()` to confirm if your code gets there

Comment: wrap the code with **runOnUiThread()** . somethin like this: `runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                LoadingCircle.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(3000).start();
            }
        });`